# Two seperate operations in one onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know if it is possible to have two onclicks, inside a HTML tag that would both work,if yes how so?. Else at least have some way of executing two separate pieces of code with one button click i.e.

```
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick=(operation example a), (operation example b)>example</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The value of the `onclick` attribute is just ordinary Javascript code. You do two things there the same way you would do it in any other script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate these with `;` semicolons and you can add numerous functions to `onclick`

```
<button type="button" onclick="operation(exampleA); operation(exampleB)">example</button>
```

The other option would be to put the two functions into one function and call this `onclick`.

```
function triggerOnClick(){
    functionOne();
    functionTwo();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" onclick="triggerOnClick()">example</button>
```

Comment: ah cool, im new here so i dont know most of the stuff or how it works. got no time to find any tutorial whatsoever for now, so it'll just be one big experience as i try to figure stackoverflow out

Comment: is there a way to make a local scope variable a global scope variable inside a function in JS? only asking cause i've been struggling with this problem where when i transfer an integer across variables it's impossable to return two values from a function unless you but them inside an array, i've tried var1=var1[0]=integershifter(firstvar,secondvar) but var1 returns as an array itself. you dont have to answer this if it's too long but do whatever you feel like it

Comment: if you define the variable outside the function at the top of your js file like `var name='Mental'`. Then in your function you can do `function sayName(){ alert(name);}`

Comment: hold on, i think it would be easier to understand what i'm saying with the source: http://pastebin.com/kaiS5ud6

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the .addEventListener() method.

```
var btn = document.getElementById('myButton');
btn.addEventListener('click', myFunctionA);
btn.addEventListener('click', myFunctionB);
btn.addEventListener('click', myFunctionC);

function myFunctionA(){ //do something
}
function myFunctionB(){ //do something
}
function myFunctionC(){ //do something
}
```

You can put as many as you like without overriding events.

PS. Disregard the term "on" when using this method. So it's only click, mousemove, mouseover, keypress, yada yada yada